# A problem about Correlated-K algorithm of MODTRAN 5

Tags: remote-sensing

When I use MODTRAN 5.2.2 to run the test case 'CorrelatedK.tp5', I get the following warning information. How I can solve this issue?

```
WARNING:  The Correlated-k option was turned off.
           The Correlated-k distributions file DATA/CORK01.BIN

           requires minimally the following assignments in file PARAMS.h:
             MXKSUB =  0        MXGAML = 33
             MXGAMD = 36        MXNUML = 23
```